# How to get my bootstrap modal at the center of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to load the bootstrap modal containing information retrieved from the database.
I'm fetching the results in the modal using AJAX .
The bootstrap modal is loaded correctly but not on the center of the page,it is loaded on the right corner of the page.
I want it to be on the center of the page

I've tried to add css properties on modal class and also search for the problem on different platform but didn't find anything.

After clicking this anchor tag I've bind the modal

```
<a href=""  onclick=" show(<?php echo $ids[$i] ?>)" class = 'fa fa-eye'        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong"'></a>
```

This is the code for ajax

```
function show(id)       
             {              

                var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET" ,"findinfo.php?id="+id,true);

                xhr.send(null);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if( (xhr.readyState == '4') && ( xhr.status == '200') )
                    {

                        document.getElementById("mbody").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    }


                }

            }
```

here is the modal I've used

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby=" exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- modal header -->
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
             </div>
             <!-- modal body -->
               <div class="modal-body" id = 'mbody'>

              </div>
              <!-- modal footer -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want The bootstrap modal on the center of the page,it is loaded on the right corner of the page.

Image shows this

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the wrapping HTML? Where you place the modal-html markup? Do you use the standard bootstrap css or a custom one (maybe than show us this as well).

Comment: Yeah I tried it with a container class and without that as well @Stretua.

Comment: Is your modal markup directly part of <body> or within an container? if in container, whats the css of that? Could you make a stackblitz example?

Comment: No , it's not directly part of the body, it is in container with no css.

Comment: What version of bootstrap you are using? v4? Could you share the html markup around your modal please? your wrapping container has no css-class or sth.? Try to use "Developer Tools" of your browser. Its always a good thing to check really used styles of your rendered code. My guess there is somewhere a "margin"-setting which overwrites the default of ".modal-dialog" class. Consider to check the linked articles in the ["How it works"-part](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/)

Comment: I've tried something like this
<div class = 'container'>

      <div class = 'row'>
              <div class = col-md-12>
                     Here is my modal...
             </div>
      </div>


</div>

Comment: do I need something else (jquery etc ) to load the modal correctly, I've never used modal before !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.modal.fade.show .modal-dialog{
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Check the post , I've updated it, given is the picture of the modal showing just at the right corner.

Comment: @mehmoodkhan, can you please create a plunker.

Answer (score 0):

You said in your comment, you have a wrapping container markup:

`<div class = 'container'> <div class = 'row'> <div class = col-md-12> Here is my modal... </div> </div> </div>`

And thats the problem. The class "col-md-12" uses css "position: relative;" and flexbox stuff. then the "fixed"-position of the modal maybe have some caveats. As I said in my comment you should read the ["How it Works"-part](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

Solution might be: Place your modal directly within body without any wrapping containers. This should be the preferred way anyhow.

Hope it helps & best regards